# Generate random numbers in an R dataframe which are constant across similar-rows

Tags: r, dataframe, split-apply-combine

I have a dataframe containing X rows per 'user', where X is not constant between users. What I would like to do is to be able to generate random numbers to fill a new column, but for each 'user' the random number is the same across all of the rows that correspond to that user. For example, the data might look something like this:

```
user    feature1     feature2
 1        "A"           "B"
 1        "L"           "L"
 1        "Q"           "B"
 1        "D"           "M"
 1        "D"           "M"
 1        "P"           "E"
 2        "A"           "B"
 2        "R"           "P"
 2        "A"           "F"
 3        "X"           "U"
...       ...           ...
```

and I would like to generate a new column that might look something like this:

```
user    feature1     feature2   new_rand
 1        "A"           "B"       0.183
 1        "L"           "L"       0.183
 1        "Q"           "B"       0.183
 1        "D"           "M"       0.183
 1        "D"           "M"       0.183
 1        "P"           "E"       0.183
 2        "A"           "B"       0.971
 2        "R"           "P"       0.971
 2        "A"           "F"       0.971
 3        "X"           "U"       0.302
...       ...           ...
```

The first approach I did was to basically use `s <- split(df, df$user)`but the dataframe contains a huge number of users and I think this is probably an extremely inefficient way to do this.

Many thanks.

Comment: This is another case of [tag:split-apply-combine]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@akrun's method is a great one-off but it doesn't leverage vectorization (we repeatedly call `rnorm` a single time within each level of `user`), so it's probably on the slow side. A more general way to do this is:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[unique(df, by = "user")[ , new_rand := rnorm(.N)],
   new_rand := i.new_rand, on = "user"]
```

What's going on here? `unique` returns a new `data.table` where all the duplicate observations (as defined by `by`, here `user`) are removed; we then add a column to this new object (`[, := ]`). Finally, this augmented `data.table` is joined back to the original table.

Note that here we only call `rnorm` once, returning a vector of exactly the right size. We then join this back to the original data set, "spreading" the value as needed across all observations of each `user`.

Or for assigning to a more specific group, say `user` and `feature1` and `feature2`:

```
grps <- c("user", "feature1", "feature2")
df[unique(df, by = grps)[ , new_rand := rnorm(.N)],
   new_rand := i.new_rand, on = grps]
```

Answer (score 3):

We can try `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'user', we get a single random number (`rnorm(1)`) and assign (`:=`) to create 'new_rand'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, new_rand := rnorm(1)  , by = user]
```

---

Or we can use `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(user) %>%
   mutate(new_rand = rnorm(1))
```

Or another option with `left_join`

```
distinct(df1, user) %>%
      mutate(new_rand=rnorm(n())) %>%
      left_join(df1, ., by='user')
```

Answer (score 3):

and a base R solution:

```
df_ <- data.frame(user = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3), feature1  = c("A", "L", "Q", "D", "D", "P", "A", "R", "A", "X"), feature2 = c("B", "L", "B", "M", "M", "E", "B", "P", "F", "U"))

tmp <- by(df_, df_[, 'user'], FUN = function(x) data.frame(x, new_rand = rnorm(1)))
do.call(rbind, tmp)

#     user feature1 feature2   new_rand
# 1.1    1        A        B -0.6145338
# 1.2    1        L        L -0.6145338
# 1.3    1        Q        B -0.6145338
# 1.4    1        D        M -0.6145338
# 1.5    1        D        M -0.6145338
# 1.6    1        P        E -0.6145338
# 2.7    2        A        B -1.4292151
# 2.8    2        R        P -1.4292151
# 2.9    2        A        F -1.4292151
# 3      3        X        U -0.3309754
```

or as per akrun's suggestion:

```
df_[, 'new_rand'] <- ave(seq_along(df_$user), df_$user, FUN = function(x) rnorm(1))
```

Comment: I think `ave` would be more compact